# Mono Project Character Lowering Problem

Tags: c#, character-encoding, monodevelop, turkish

I am trying to develop an ASP.NET web application on a Mac using Mono Project.
But because of a character problem, it throws an error of 'ınital Catalog'. That happens because, when Mono compiles my code, it converts my 'I' s  to 'ı' which is not an English word. So I can't write UserID = 1 or Initial Catalog = myDB in the code. 
How can I fix this?
Thanks alot.

Comment: Looks like you have a space in your variable name?

Comment: "ınital Catalog" is not an error message.  Show us the compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
I deleted web.config code of

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
```

Comment: In Turkish a lowercase "I" is "ı", and a lowercase "İ" is "i". No other culture makes a distinction between dotted i and dotless i. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I and http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/whats-wrong-with-turkey.html